# Connecting to MonetDB using ODBC

Tags: unixodbc, monetdb

I have tried using unixODBC (version 2.3.2) and the MonetDB ODBC client (version 11.21.5) on both Mac OS X 10.9 and Debian 8, but cannot connect through ODBC using `isql` on client machines to a MonetDB server running on Debian 8, although it works fine from the server machine.

When issuing `isql -v voc` on the client machines I get the following error message:

> [08001][unixODBC][MonetDB][ODBC Driver 11.21.5]Client unable to establish connection
>   [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Here is my `.odbc.ini` file:

```
[voc]
Driver          = MonetDB
Description     = MonetDB voc test database
Servername      = <<left out>>
Port            = 50000
UserName        = monetdb
Password        = monetdb
Database        = voc
```

and my `/opt/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` file:

```
[MonetDB]
Description     = ODBC Driver for MonetDB SQL Server 
Driver          = /usr/local/monetdb/lib/libMonetODBC.so
Setup           = /usr/local/monetdb/lib/libMonetODBCs.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

Interestingly enough I am able to connect using `mclient` from client machines and the server machine as well using the following command line:

`mclient -d voc -u monetdb -h <<left out>>`

The server is configured as follows:

`monetdbd get all testing/testDBfarm/`

```
property         value
hostname         <<left out>>
dbfarm           testing/testDBfarm/
status           monetdbd[37007] 1.7 (Jul2015) is serving this dbfarm
mserver          /usr/bin/mserver5
logfile          testing/testDBfarm//merovingian.log
pidfile          testing/testDBfarm//merovingian.pid
sockdir          /tmp
port             50000
exittimeout      60
forward          proxy
discovery        true
discoveryttl     600
control          no
passphrase       <unknown>
mapisock         /tmp/.s.monetdb.50000
controlsock      /tmp/.s.merovingian.50000
```

Is there anything I am missing here which is needed to let clients connect to a MonetDB server through ODBC?

Answer (score 0):

The debug log of isql (running `ODBCDEBUG=/tmp/odbclog isql test`)  revealed the problem:
The MonetDB ODBC driver has ignored the Servername parameter in my config file.

.odbc.ini:

> Servername      = *LEFT OUT*

Log:

> SQLConnect: DSN=voc UID=monetdb PWD=monetdb host=localhost port=50000 database=voc.

It is quite unfortunate, that most ODBC drivers use a different name for specifying the  server's hostname or IP-address: Servername, Host, or even Server (See: http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html)

Thus, for MonetDB's ODBC driver we need to use `Host` to specify the hostname, instead of `Servername` or `Server`, as for Postgres or MySQL, e.g.